# ERRORSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, mysql

verifiqué los parámetros pero no encuentro el error, pensé que era por el hash pero no.

```
/*recuperacion de contraseñas mediante email*/

//generar email aleatorio//

 function sa($longitud){
    $caracteres = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $numero_caracteres = strlen($caracteres);
    $string_aleatorio = '';

    for($i=0; $i < $longitud; $i++){
        $string_aleatorio .= $caracteres[rand(0,$numero_caracteres - 1)]; 
    }

    return $string_aleatorio;
    }  
    try{
    if(isset($_POST['enviar_email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        Conexion::abrir_conexion();

        if(!RepositorioUsuario :: email_existe(Conexion :: obtener_conexion(), $email)){
            return;
        }

        $usuario = RepositorioUsuario::obtener_usuario_por_email(Conexion::obtener_conexion(),$email);

        $nombre_usuario = $usuario -> obtener_nombre();
        $string_aleatorio = sa(10);

        $url_secreta = hash('sha256', $string_aleatorio . $nombre_usuario);

        $peticion_generada = RepositorioRecuperacionClave :: generar_peticion(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $usuario-> obtener_id(), $url_secreta);

        Conexion::cerrar_conexion();

        if($peticion_generada){
            Redireccion::redirigir(RUTA_SERVIDOR);
        }


    }}catch(PDOException $ex){
        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();

    }
```

el repositorio de la recuperacion clave

```
<?php
class RepositorioRecuperacionClave{
    public static function generar_peticion($conexion, $id_usuario, $url_secreta){
        $peticion_generada = false;

        if(isset($conexion)){
            try{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO recuperacion_clave(usuario_id, url_secreta, fecha) VALUES (:usuario_id, : url_secreta, NOW())";

                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);               


                $sentencia -> bindParam(':usuario_id', $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sentencia -> bindParam(':url_secreta', $url_secreta, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);

                $peticion_generada = $sentencia -> execute();
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();

            }


        }
        return $peticion_generada;
    }
}
```

y en la tabla de la bd los campos que agregué son (id,uduario_id,url_secreta,fecha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que el problema esta en el archivo `repositorio de la recuperacion clave` noto dos errores

1.- En la linea donde almacenas tu query hay un espacio en `: url_secreta` esto es un error, debe de ir todo junto, tu query debería quedar asi:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO recuperacion_clave(usuario_id, url_secreta, fecha) VALUES (:usuario_id, :url_secreta, NOW())";
```

2.- En tu script estas repitiendo la linea `$sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);` justo después de vincular las variables en el query PDO con sus respectivos valores:

```
$sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);               

$sentencia -> bindParam(':usuario_id', $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sentencia -> bindParam(':url_secreta', $url_secreta, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
```

Quita la linea que esta después de los `bindParam` y ya con esto tu programa debería funcionar

Te dejo como debería quedar tu código al final ya con las modificaciones realizadas.

```
<?php
class RepositorioRecuperacionClave{
    public static function generar_peticion($conexion, $id_usuario, $url_secreta){
        $peticion_generada = false;

        if(isset($conexion)){
            try{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO recuperacion_clave(usuario_id, url_secreta, fecha) VALUES (:usuario_id, : url_secreta, NOW())";

                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);               

                $sentencia -> bindParam(':usuario_id', $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sentencia -> bindParam(':url_secreta', $url_secreta, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $peticion_generada = $sentencia -> execute();
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $peticion_generada;
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo se me escapó eso